# Turkey's list of designated terrorist organizations?

Tags: terrorism, policy, turkey

According to [this news article](http://english.al-akhbar.com/content/turkey-blacklists-al-nusra-front-terror-group):

> Turkey blacklists al-Nusra Front as terror group
>   Turkey added al-Qaeda's franchise in neighboring Syria to a list of terrorist organizations on Tuesday

Where can this official list be seen? (preferably online)

A year ago this list used to be at http://www.egm.gov.tr/temuh/terorgrup1.html, but now that link returns an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can see the official declaration from government. but its only turkish

http://www.resmigazete.gov.tr/eskiler/2014/06/20140603-16-1.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Their new site is found at

http://www.egm.gov.tr/EN/Pages/terrorist_organizations.aspx

I couldn't find the al-nusra front specifically, but it talks about al-qaeda extensively.

Comment: Thanks! It looks more like a general information page though... By the way, the list used to be in Turkish only, and it probably still is not available in English.